# What are these > at the right of unterminated lines, when I do a systemctl status or a journalctl for example?

Tags: debian, less, systemctl

When I do a `sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service` or a `journalctl -xe` on *Debian 11* I have this output:

[image]

many lines are ended with **>** characters and I don't know how to handle these lines to see their remaining characters.

Or to disable this feature and see the commands doing a normal output, dumping the whole content of these lines, and not only the characters that can fit horizontally.

Comment: That looks like something drawn by whatever pager you're using here, rather that the `systemctl` itself.  I've removed the [tag:console] tag, as you're clearly on a window-system virtual terminal here, not a console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the full text using the `Right Key (>)` of your keyboard.
If I'm not wrong when you use some commands like `journalctl options...`, `systemctl options...` these page their output through `less` command.
This happens when the output lines are bigger than the width of your terminal.

If you want to avoid this behavior you can use:

```
systemctl status --no-pager elasticsearch.service
journalctl -xe --no-pager
```

Or if the command doesn't have some option like `--no-pager` you can try piping the output to `cat` command:

```
systemctl status elasticsearch.service | cat
```

Comment: You can also ask `less` to wrap long lines by pressing `-S` once it’s started, or adding `S` to the `LESS` environment variable.

Comment: @StephenKitt Great tip! I didn't know about that. I will use it better, it's more comfortable for me to see the full output instead of paging this one.

Comment: Piping through `cat` (or anything else) does have some side effects though, because `systemctl` no longer sees its output connected to a terminal, so colouring and other fancy formatting might get disabled and the output might be buffered (so that you won't see all of it immediately).

Comment: @TooTea, it seems that `systemctl` understands the `PAGER` environment variable, so if you like its colouring, you could always `PAGER=cat`.

Comment: @TooTea Yes, I've noticed that, I don't know how it works. Because if you use `neofetch | cat` or `neofetch > neo && cat neo` you will see the colouring output. And if you see or edit the file `neo` you can see the color format like `[[32m^[[1m`. Maybe some commands like neofetch have the future for redirecting the color format too.

Answer (score 1):

Press right arrow on a keyboard to scroll horizontally. You will be surprised by what you find.

Comment: I'd tried, but I'd hit `:q` before trying, always. That's why I never noticed that the right arrow key was doing something... In fact, I was even wondering why it did nothing!